# how can i fix the this offset rig problem with the hand?

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

so i was making this model for a while now and i rigged it and everything, but for some reason the fingers arent on the bones when i rotate them more than about 20
[image: picture]

does anyone know whats going on and how do i fix it?
[image]

Comment: It's likely the weights aren't strong enough and the model will lag slightly behind the bones. I suggest opening weight paint and adjusting it or recalculating the parent.

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work @NascentSpace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out because i made the parent bone weights ovelap with the child, this caused the problem